# Improving performance of knockout foreach?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a list of 50 items, each of which has a few blocks like this:

```
<!-- ko if: replyCount() == 1 -->
    <p class="reply-count-label">reply</p>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: replyCount() != 1 -->
    <p class="reply-count-label">replies</p>
<!-- /ko -->
```

This is within a virtual `foreach` loop.

Even with only 50 elements, the page is taking ~1s to render, so the user experience is pretty lousy as things are moving around as they render.  These observables aren't being updated or anything - it's just the initial load time that's slow.

The only thing I do on load is map:

```
 self.posts = ko.mapping.fromJS(model.questions);
```

I'm looking for ways to optimize this.  Is the culprit here my use of `ko.mapping`, or is it with the use of virtual elements, or `if` + `foreach` bindings, or a combination?

Comment: You need to do some timing experiments. Try temporarily removing those conditional sections and see if it makes a noticeable difference. If it doesn't, they aren't the problem. Output the current time to the console both before and after calling `fromJS`. Nothing can substitute for actually measuring where your program spends its time; we developers are notorious for making guesses and getting them wrong.

Comment: Also I would try to change all code above to: 
`<p class="reply-count-label" data-bind = "text : replyCount()==1 ? 'replies' : 'reply'"></p>`

Comment: I render upwards of a few hundred complex nested elements in "a blink of an eye" on a PC. There is nothing inherently that slow with the approach or KO bindings - try to isolate the *actual* slow
 bit. (Also, I would probably write the above using `text` and a computed observable ..)

Comment: The slowness can be caused by many things, including complex CSS rules. Try commenting out the CSS to see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely something worth trying here -

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: replyCounts, as: 'replyCount' }">
    <li data-bind="replyCount === 1">Show me</li>
</ul>
```

This way you don't have to access the function each time to access the value, as it has already been resolved.  I can't test the results that this will give you because I don't have access to a fiddle or anything to replicate the problem so I can't see the differences so if this doesn't provide value then feel free to let me know and I can remove it.